# Pasar parametros en onclick de una celda

Tags: php

no se si se pueda hacer en esta forma. En mi pagina principal php , cargo mediante un bucle filas en una tabla. En una de las celdas tengo unas coordenadas, que necesito pasar por GET al archivo mapita.php . 
En este bucle cargo 4 variables, var1/2/3/4 (hasta aqui todo perfecto).
Este es un fragmento del bucle donde cargo los datos en la tabla :

```html
            echo "    <td class='tabla_t'>". $vasociado . "</td>\n";
            echo "    <td class='tabla_t'>". $vfecha . "</td>\n";
            echo "    <td class='tabla_t'>" . $vnumero . "</td>\n";
            echo "    <td class='tabla_t' onclick=\"'location.href='mapita.php?dato1='". $var1. "' &dato2='". $var2. "' &dato3='". $var3. "' &dato4='". $var4. "'\";>" . $var1 . '-' .$var2 . ' / ' . $var3 . "</td>\n";
            echo "    <td class='tabla_t'>" . substr($vnom . ", " . $vape,0,30) . "</td>\n";
```

En el archivo mapita.php tengo :

```html
$v1=$_GET['dato1'];
$v2=$_GET['dato2'];
$v3=$_GET['dato3'];
$v4=$_GET['dato4'];
```

La idea es que al hacer click en la celda que tengo el onclick, se ejecute el location a otro php y se pasen los parametros. No sdoy con la sintaxis correctas, se puede hacer asi ?

Comment: Tienes unos espacios en blanco que rompen tu URL del onclick. Justo antes de cada &. Quitalos

Comment: ok , igual el primer problema es que no me toma el onclick ... se puede usar onclick en una celda sin que sea boton ?

Answer (score 1):

En html si es posible que hagas click en un elemento (incluso en una celda de una tabla). En general, tu problema es porque no se te esta formando bien la sentencia javascript. Tu html final deberia quedar como:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class='tabla_t'>1</td>
    <td class='tabla_t'>2</td>
    <td class='tabla_t'>3</td>
    <td class='tabla_t' onclick="location.href='mapita.php?dato1=11&dato2=12&dato3=13&dato4=14;'">11-12 / 13</td>
    <td class='tabla_t'>nombre, apellidos, VAPE VAPE</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

fijate en el onclick. su valor (lo que debe tener entre comillas) es un javascript, por lo que es una sentencia. en este caso, location.href=... Por ello, NO debe empezar por ' (que es un literal). Sin embargo, cuando le asignas el valor a href, este SI tiene un ' al inicio y un ' al final. Los datos NO tienen ' (en una uri no se admite ese caracter, te lo cambiaria por un literal y tu resultado contendria en el destino dicha comilla)

Para ver la diferencia, utiliza el inspector de codigo de tu navegador, y mira en la pestaña de consola javascript que ocurre cuando haces click. Si da un error, es fallo de javascript.

Comment: Ok buenísimo, no estoy pudiendo reemplazar los datos por variables, que estoy haciendo mal ?

echo "    <td class='tabla_td' onclick="location.href='mapita.php?dato1='. $var1 .'&dato2='. $var2 .'&dato3='.$var3 .'&dato4='. $var4 .';">" . $vnivel . '-' .$visla . ' / ' . $vposi . "</td>\n";

Comment: te falla el escapado de las dobles comillas. Date cuenta que abres dobles comillas en el `echo`, y las cierras en el `onclick`. En tu caso, puedes escapar las iniciales y las finales. Esto deberia valerte: `echo " <td class='tabla_td' onclick=\"location.href='mapita.php?dato1='. $var1 .'&dato2='. $var2 .'&dato3='.$var3 .'&dato4='. $var4 .';">" . $vnivel . '-' .$visla . ' / ' . $vposi . \"</td>\n";`